# SQL - Identity Column Overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a junction table `UserStamps` between the table `Users` and `Stamps`.

The `UserStamps` table has the following columns:

- ID (bigint) [Identity 1,1]
- UserId (int)
- StampId (int)
- Quantity (smallint)

Each user can have up to 150 stamp at a time but he can acquire/remove/exchange stamps.

By acquiring, a new row is added.

By removing, the row is deleted from the table but exchanging replace one stamp Id with the other.

My question is: By continuous adding/removing of rows the ID column will reach the overflow state and it is known that identity always counts from the last number and ignore gaps between numbers.

When the counter reaches maximum will it fill any gaps between the IDs if not how can I handle the overflow situation ?

Comment: worry about it when you get there. that's a 64-bit integer, you're going to be needing to be adding TONS of user stamps to get there. like 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 user stamps.

Comment: [{Link} is this answer relevant to your question?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5305271/491243) and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674420/what-will-append-if-the-maximum-value-of-an-identity-column-is-reached).

Comment: How many users and stamp records do you want to be able to handle?  You have to have that number before you can pick the correct data type.

Comment: If you use a `BIGINT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert **one thousand rows every second**, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit ....