# Prevent overflow on identity id column when performing frequent inserts

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which has an id column and is specified as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    name text,
    description text,
    CONSTRAINT foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I am updating this table quite frequently (every 5min) but I am using 'ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING'

As described in this post [serial in postgres is being increased even though I added on conflict do nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37204749/serial-in-postgres-is-being-increased-even-though-i-added-on-conflict-do-nothing) it is expected that the id increments using this setup.

However based on this post [What happens to the primary key Id when it goes over the limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305232/what-happens-to-the-primary-key-id-when-it-goes-over-the-limit) I do need to worry about the counter going over the limit.

**How do I prevent an error from occurring in this scenario?**
To be clear, I don't need the values to be gap-less nor do I necessarily need to have the values be in sequence, I just need uniqueness and I would like to be able to use as small a datatype as possible (I would like to switch to smallint at some point)

Possible solutions I can see:

1. Manually ensuring no duplicates would be inserted before perfoming the actual insert as is done in this solution: [POSTGRES - prevent serial incrementation with ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720340/postgres-prevent-serial-incrementation-with-on-conflict-do-nothing). **Downside:** Computationally am I not checking the uniqueness constraint twice per insert now?
2. Somehow have postgres use gap-less sequential values. **Downside:** Seems like this is not the intention of how postgres should work
3. Have postgres re-start the counter when it loops around rather than throwing an error: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createsequence.html Says there is a **cycle** option which sounds like exactly what I need.
4. Just go with it and accept that I need to use bigint

**Update**

so far:

1. Feasible option but as mentioned there is a cpu resource penalty
2. Bad idea based on this post [PostgreSQL gapless sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984196/postgresql-gapless-sequences)
3. Not possible since this would lead to duplicate id's
4. Best option in most cases

For my particular case I would like to further determine whether option 1 might not be better than option 4 after all:

- Table with id's has about 20k rows
- A batch insert with nearly all 20k duplicate items is made every 5 min
- The table which references the one with the id's contains 10bn+ rows and runs on timescaledb
- If we use bigint(8byte) instead of int(4byte) we use (10bn*(8-4)byte) ca. 40GB uncompressed additional space
- I guess with timescaledb this would be somewhat compressed down to maybe 10GB additional space used for the id's

Is it still better to go for option 4 over option 1 in this case, given the infrequent updates made to the table and the space usage for storing id's in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the correct solution is another one: change the data type of the identity column to `bigint`. Then you won't run out of sequence values.

Performing that change with a simple `ALTER TABLE` will rewrite it and lock it for the duration of the statement. There are more complicated ways to do it with less down tiime, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33504982/6464308).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I would prefer not to use this method is that I need to reference this id in a very large second table. As it has very many rows, the space savings from using `smallint` vs `bigint` start to become relevant. What is the issue with using the `cycle` option?

Comment: The cycle option repeats values. Guaranteeing either duplicate ids or you delete data before it cycles. Storage space is cheep compared to the alternatives.

Comment: @Belayer Good point. To give some quick reference. The table I am inserting to has about 20k rows, the table which references it has about 10Bn Rows. So uncompressed Bigint would use about 80GB and smalling 20GB - Difference of 60GB. As that table uses timescaledb I would guess that compressed that 60GB reduces to a difference of maybe 10GB. Is 10GB worth less than computational cost of checking uniqueness in a batch insert of 10k values to a 20k row table every 5min? (obv. just looking for an approximate answer, not math)

Comment: Perhaps you should update the question with that information.